# How to pass value from gridview inside modal pop up extender to textbox in parent form?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I tried to execute below codes to pass selected row value from gridview inside modal pop up extender to textbox in parent form but it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    txttitle.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Any exception throw to you?

Comment: You have to update datacontrols in the parent page. You can throw an update panel and manually update it like UpdatePanel1.Update();

Comment: I've tried that before Sir but it gives me an error. What I did is I put a script manager before update panel and I put the textbox inside update panel. But whenever i tried to debug it an error appears "Only one instance of script manager can be added to the page".

Answer (score 1):

Passing values from ajax popup (gridview) to parent page textbox.
This links help you.

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/04/masterdetail_with_the_gridview.html

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/modalpopupextender_example_for.html